# Does Skia work with FMX Styles in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, skia, firemonkey-style, skia4delphi

I have a simple project with Skia Enabled and `GlobalUseSkia` turned on like this:

```
GlobalUseSkia := True
```

But every time I enable my custom FMX Style, then my UI is just blank white:

[image: Blank Delphi App]

It works without the FMX Style though and also works if I disable Skia.

I am using Delphi 11.3 and Skia4Delphi 3.2

Comment: You can use Skia and Style file (I do it). How did you load your style file ?